# Not Working/Not Scheduling Job using WorkManager When App is Closed

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

As we use firebase job dispatcher to run a job when firebase notification is received there was no other way to run code on the notification received that was old, now WorkManager is here.
It is working fine when the application is opened but when the application is closed it does not work, but firebase job dispatcher works fine, I want it to work using WorkManager API.

I tried in the following way it is 100% working code and doing the job using WorkManager but only when the application is opened, I want it to work when the application is not opened, I know that we register a service for the case of firebase job dispatcher in manifest but what to do for WorkManager -:)

I tried the ways that are related to job dispatcher but they didn't work e.g service in manifest etc...

public class BackgroundWorker extends ListenableWorker {

```
private static final ListenableFuture listenableFuture = null ;

/**
 * @param appContext   The application {@link Context}
 * @param workerParams Parameters to setup the internal state of this worker
 */

public BackgroundWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(appContext, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListenableFuture<ListenableWorker.Result> startWork() {
    // Do your work here.

    // Return a ListenableFuture<>
    return listenableFuture;
}

@Override
public void onStopped() {
    // Cleanup because you are being stopped.
}

public void toast(String msg, Context applicationContext)
{
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"),remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));


    scheduleJob();
}
/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */

/**
 * Schedule a job using workmanager.
 */

private void scheduleJob() {
    String unique_id = getRandomString(6);
    Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
            .putString("bulksmswebapi", unique_id)
            .build();
    // [START dispatch_job]

    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            // The Worker needs Network connectivity
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            // Needs the device to be charging
           // .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .build();
    OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest =
            // Tell which work to execute
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundWorker.class)
                    // Sets the input data for the ListenableWorker
                    .setInputData(inputData)
                    // If you want to delay the start of work by 60 seconds
                    .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    // Set a backoff criteria to be used when retry-ing
                  //  .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffCriteria.EXPONENTIAL, 30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    // Set additional constraints
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance()
            // Use ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE to cancel and delete any existing pending
            // (uncompleted) work with the same unique name. Then, insert the newly-specified
            // work.
            .enqueueUniqueWork(unique_id, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, workRequest);
    // [END dispatch_job]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved by me, Answer to the question is Just make a Worker extended class and Don't use any Toast or other messages then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your worker code does nothing.  You are returning null ListenableFuture, meaning WorkManager can't do anything.  onStartWork is also explicitly marked as @NonNull so I'm not sure what you're doing there.  You have a method that's never executed (toast) because you don't call it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I removed the code, I am just asking about how to execute this code when the app is not running, this is example code.

Comment: Full Example is like, When i receive a notification from firebase then how i can start this worker without opening the app? did you understand?